# Relative paths when hosting static single page website on Dropbox

Tags: html, dropbox, static-html

To have an direct access of a file on Dropbox, you have to replace the shared link's subdomain `www` with `dl`. The main domain gets redirected from `dropbox` to `dropboxusercontent`.

I wonder how (if possible) to host a static single page website with external CSS and image files. These external files are in sibling directories, but the html file doesn't seem "to be aware" about these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible with a share link, since relative paths don't work. (Each path has its own signature in the URL.)

However, you can do this with a public folder, or you can use third-party hosting. I'll refrain from plugging my startup here, but there are a number of good options. :-)

Comment: AFAIK the public folders are not direct links, but framed in Dropbox's webpage. Replacing the subdomain's `www` with `dl` only resolves to a `404`... 
Ps. I'd have loved to go with site44, but this is a single site that I don't care much about but still want a custom domain for, hence not really worth paying recurringly for (except for the domain name)..

Comment: You need to replace `www.dropbox.com` with `dl.dropboxusercontent.com`, but relative links still won't work. As I said, the public folder should work for you.